# Getting images out of Slack – webhooks or otherwise

Tags: slack-api, slack

I'm building a live blogging application that will take all posts on a particular Slack channel and turn them into posts on a CMS using a little nodejs app in between.

Text-based posts are all good using outgoing webhooks – but I can't work out any way to get attachments (images, videos etc) out of Slack.

Their own documentation [here](https://api.slack.com/outgoing-webhooks) says that:

> Please note that the content of message attachments will not be included in the outgoing POST data.

But surely there's some way to do it!

I'm fine with writing an app to handle a slash command or similar. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice would be to use Bot-User here. They can easily send images, files, etc out of slack.

With Outgoing-Webhooks sending message attachments will not be possible.

Another way (Not a good way and will not work everytime) can be to include the attachment in a slach command via link. 
For ex.

```
/post MESSAGE img1.com
```

In this way you can post the image along with your message. I would advice to go with bot-user.

Comment: That was easy! Don't know why I hadn't spotted that. I've now made a little app using the NodeJS RTM starter. Nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to run the [microblog proxy server](https://github.com/vitaldatalink/microblog), a web service which parses the messages and images from a Slack channel into RSS (XML) which can easily be parsed by **nodejs**.